# Youtube api for live tv channel streaming

Tags: android, live-streaming, youtube-channels

I am making live tv streaming application for android.Is there any youtube api for live tv streaming?

Comment: Is there any other api other than youtube?

Comment: Is there any one who tried live tv channel streaming

Comment: Any solution other than apis?

Comment: Plz share how you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

They do have a Live service, but no information on an API as it is only limited to certain partners

**References:**
http://www.youtube.com/live
http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2011/04/youtube-is-going-live.html

Comment: Live streaming in flash or mp4?

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything in here 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_retrieving_live_events

Comment: But the api for channels is not specified :(

Comment: Is there any other api for live tv streaming

Answer (score 0):

Once check your network connectivity and try again, i think your internet speed is high your issue will solve